# How do I create a mutable List backed by Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, decorator, mutable

How can I return a `List<E>` backed by `Map<K, E>` if I have a method for mapping `Map` values to keys `valueToKeyMapper`?

```java
class Foo {
   private Map<Integer, String> backedMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

   public List<String> getList() {
      // NEED TO RETURN LIST BACKED BY MAP
   }

   public String getById(Integer id) {
      return backedMap.get(id);
   }

   private static Integer valueToKeyMapper(String value) {
      // just as exampl. In reality value will be POJO with method like getId()
      return value.hashCode();
   }
}
```

The code should work like this (simple example):

```java
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.getList().add("something");
String value = foo.getById("something".hashCode());
// I should see something
```

Notes:

- `List` should be mutable and changes must be propagated in underlying `Map`
- I can't modify public methods of object `Foo`, because it's used in other projects
- I don't care about order in `List`
- The `getById` method should continue to work fast

Comment: If the add to the List what should go in the Map?

Comment: It seems you think hashCodes are unique IDs. They're not. Don't treat them as such.

Comment: When value is added to a list, the map should be modified like this:
`map.put(Foo.valueToKeyMapper(value), value)`

Comment: hashCodes are just for sake of breverty, in reality `value` is business object with method `value.getId()`

Comment: *I don't care about order in List* Then you need not `List` but `Set` and `HashSet` is backed by `HashMap` anyway.

Comment: You need to create an implementation of the `List` interface that fulfills your criteria. A nested class is fine. Please try that and come back if you run into problems.

Comment: Do you really need a `List`? If a `Collection` will do, you can use `Map.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :---

---

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();  

Set keys = backedMap.keySet();
for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
           Integer key = (Integer) i.next();
           String value = (String) backedMap.get(key);
           list.add(value);
       }


 //To print Values in ArrayList :--    
    for(String s : list) {
              System.out.println("printing element -- " + s);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

An attempt using this `List` on github: [ListBackedByMap.java](https://github.com/lislon/java-list-backed-by-map/blob/master/src/main/java/org/lislon/ListBackedByMap.java)

It uses [ForwardingList](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained) to maintain internal copy of the list in the map.

There are two issues with this impl I found:

1. It maintains additional copy of elements in memory
2. It doesn't throws `ConcurrentModificationException` on attempt to modify list in iterator.

Tests avaliable [here](https://github.com/lislon/java-list-backed-by-map).